# I need to find the distance of each duplicated letter

Tags: python-3.x, import, distance, python-itertools, pairwise

```
from itertools import pairwise

l_h = []
l_r = []
for index, elem  in enumerate("THISISTHEARHGRAYR"):
    if elem == "R":
        l_r.append(index)
    if elem == "H":
        l_h.append(index)

H = [b - a for a, b in pairwise(l_h)]
R = [b - a for a, b in pairwise(l_r)]
print(H,R)[enter image description here][1]
```

And I  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMC5.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMC5.png If i run this code I get error `cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools'`

Comment: Your code works as intended. What version of python are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your version of itertools does not have the `pairwise` function. You can check its available functions in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (select Python version in the upper left corner).

I suggest creating your own implementation of `pairwise`, I found [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to work well.

**Code and output:**

```py
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable) # Note that tee is from itertools
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

l_h = []
l_r = []
for index, elem in enumerate("THISISTHEARHGRAYR"):
    if elem == "R":
        l_r.append(index)
    if elem == "H":
        l_h.append(index)

# Added -1 to count letters BETWEEN duplicates
H = [ b - a - 1 for a, b in pairwise(l_h) ]
R = [ b - a - 1 for a, b in pairwise(l_r) ]

print(H, R)
```

outputs

`[5, 3] [2, 2]`.

Also, upgrading to Python 3.10 should work (I have not tested this).